# correct usage of phrasal verb, bring that incident up and bring his words

Tags: phrasal-verbs

**Scenario 1**

Suppose that you and your friend, Mary, have just interviewed your ex-coworker, David, who wanted a job at your company. After he has left, Mary says something to you about him.

(1) Mary said, "Do you remember David?"

I replied, "He looks familiar."

She said, "At least fifteen years ago, we both worked with him at ABC Supermarket."

I said, "Right. I remember him now."

She said, "He was fired for swearing and spitting at our manager."

I said, "I remember that. I'm glad you **brought that incident up**."

**Scenario 2**

Suppose that you are talking to your cousin that you need money to pay your rent.

(2) I said, "I lost my job six months ago. I'm running out of savings. What should I do?"

He said, "I wish I could help. I lost my job last month too. Don't worry. I remember that our uncle said he's always willing to help us with anything."

I said, "I'm glad you **brought his words up**."

Is it correct to say "brought that incident up" and "brought his words up"?

Answer (score 1):

Phrasal verbs can be intransitive or transitive.  According to [Lexico](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823040735/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/phrasal-verbs),

> The verb and adverb elements which make up intransitive phrasal verbs are never separated:

✓  We broke up two years ago.

✗  We broke two years ago up.

With transitive verbs,

> [i]f the direct object  is a noun, you can say

✓ They pulled the house down.

✓ They pulled down the house.

> If the object is a pronoun, ...then the object always comes between the verb and the adverb:

✓ They pulled it down.

✗ They pulled down it.

In your examples,

> "brought that incident up"

and

> "brought his words up",

*brought* is transitive, and *that incident* and *his words* are both nouns.   The word sequence is hence fine.